# Do Emberjs Handlebars have a conditional similar to {{elsif}}?

Tags: ember.js, conditional-statements, handlebars.js

I want to create a conditional using more than just a boolean conditional (AKA just 'if' and 'else'). Is this possible or is there an alternate solution?

EXAMPLE

```
editMode: false,
deleteMode: false

    {{#if editMode}}
      edit mode happens
    {{#elsif deleteMode}}
      delete mode happens
    {{else}}
      something else happens
    {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll just have to do multiple if statements or nested if statements which would evaluate the same as your else if statement.

```
{{#if conditional}}
    Foooo
{{else}}
   {{#if conditional2}}
      Barrrr
   {{else}}
      Bazzzz
   {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

#### Update 2/07/2015

As of EmberJS 1.10 you can use else if!

```
{{#if foo}}
foo
{{else if bar}}
bar
{{/if}}
```

read more about it here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html

Comment: Nested conditionals is a good alternative. It's a shame they don't have {{elsif}} statements, but I'll take what I can get. :)

Comment: It probably does not have `elsif` statements because of their harsh "no-logic-here" policy. That's why there's no comparison operators as well - in the end, if you can only have boolean clauses, why would you have an `elsif`? With this in mind, it would be confusing if you had an `if` about a variable with an `elsif` with another one: it's like doing two complete different tests instead of testing two things on the same subject.

Comment: hah, they actually just added an else if :)  There are circumstances where it's a plausible thing, think about switch statements. http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html